# "Unable to mount internal sd card" after rom flashing

Tags: android, adb, custom-rom

Phone: LeTv Le 2

ROM: AOSP Extended https://forum.xda-developers.com/le-2/development/rom-aospextended-rom-v6-0-t3841473

Guide Followed While Flashing TWRP and Magisk: https://www.guidingtech.com/59895/le-2-rooting-guide-twrp-installation/

Problem:
Everything was fine until I tried Downloading an apk using chrome and it couldn't find storage/emulated/0 and none of the apps were able to access storage..

So I fired up ADB and $ adb shell gave me a list of folders with no storage folder.

~ # ls
boot                       init.recovery.service.rc   selinux_version
cache                      init.recovery.usb.rc       sepolicy
charger                    license                    service_contexts
data                       oem                        sideload
default.prop               persist                    supersu
dev                        proc                       sys
dsp                        property_contexts          system
etc                        recovery                   tmp
file_contexts              res                        twres
firmware                   root                       ueventd.rc
init                       sbin                       usbstorage
init.rc                    sdcard
init.recovery.hlthchrg.rc  seapp_contexts

I realised I had no /storage/emulated/0 folder.

I tried reflashing the rom, it didn't make a difference.
I tried flashing a different ROM, no result.

I tried to open the folder sdcard, it says 'sdcard' is not mounted.

I tried mounting it using adb but it didn't work.
I tried symlinking storage/emulated/0 to sdcard, no results.

How to I get my sdcard back/mount it?

Comment: I tried creating storage/emulated/0 and symlinking it to sdcard, no results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IDK what the issue was but it got resolved by flashing Graphene Kernel.

Here's what I did:

1. adb reboot bootloader
2. adb reboot bootloader
   fastboot oem unlock

fastboot oem unlock-go
fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.2.1-0-s2.img
fastboot format userdata

3. Flashed the ROM.
4. Fasjed Gapps
5. Flashed MAgisk.

Reboot Phone.

5. Flashed : https://forum.xda-developers.com/le-2/development/project-illusionkernel-v1-0-t3677897